# Add class to multiple cached jquery elements

Tags: jquery

With jQuery is it possible to add a class to multiple cached elements at the same time. I know i could do the following:

```
cachedElement1 = $('#div1');
cachedElement2 = $('#div2');

cachedElement1.addClass('someclass');
cachedElement2.addClass('someclass');
```

But is there a short way of doing it.  So something like the below which doesn't actually work.

```
$(cachedElement1,cachedElement2).addClass('someclass');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `add()` to add elements to a selector. Try this:

```
cachedElement1.add(cachedElement2).addClass('someclass');
```

[API reference: Add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like this:

```
cachedElement1.add(cachedElement2).addClass('someclass');
```

Comment: Thanks Nelson works great, but i picked Rorys answer as the solution due api reference link as that was the only way to choose between the 2 :)